# UnhandledError: Cannot redefine property: stack

Tags: azure, arm, microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

I'm having problems deploying the application via toolkit, error appears -> Cannot redefine property: stack

> stack: UnhandledError: Cannot redefine property: stack at getError
> (<REDACTED: user-file-path>:14:5819447) at Object.wrapRun (<REDACTED:
> user-file-path>:14:5819625) at processTicksAndRejections
> (node:<REDACTED: user-file-path>:95:5) at ArmDeployDriver.execute
> (<REDACTED: user-file-path>:14:5553122) at Lifecycle.executeImpl
> (<REDACTED: user-file-path>:14:5427203) at Lifecycle.execute
> (<REDACTED: user-file-path>:14:5424360) at Coordinator.provision
> (<REDACTED: user-file-path>:14:5470516) at Coordinator. (<REDACTED:
> user-file-path>:14:6119329) at FxCore.provisionResources (<REDACTED:
> user-file-path>:14:6047609) at FxCore.exports.EnvWriterMW (<REDACTED:
> user-file-path>:14:5958667) at FxCore.exports.ContextInjectorMW
> (<REDACTED: user-file-path>:14:6123081) at
> FxCore.exports.ConcurrentLockerMW (<REDACTED:
> user-file-path>:14:6122032) at envLoaderMWImpl (<REDACTED:
> user-file-path>:14:5958547) at FxCore. (<REDACTED:
> user-file-path>:14:5957475) at FxCore.exports.ProjectMigratorMWV3
> (<REDACTED: user-file-path>:14:6153660) at
> FxCore.exports.ErrorHandlerMW (<REDACTED: user-file-path>:14:6123578)
> at FxCore. (<REDACTED: user-file-path>:14:6119329)

azure.bicep:

```
    @maxLength(20)
    @minLength(4)
    param resourceBaseName string
    param storageSku string
    
    @description('Required when create Azure Bot service')
    param botAadAppClientId string
    
    @secure()
    @description('Required by Bot Framework package in your bot project')
    param botAadAppClientSecret string
    
    param webAppSKU string
    
    @maxLength(42)
    param botDisplayName string
    
    param serverfarmsName string = resourceBaseName
    param webAppName string = resourceBaseName
    
    param storageName string = resourceBaseName
    param location string = resourceGroup().location
    
    param microsoftAppTenantId string
    param tabDomain string
    
    // Azure Storage that hosts your static web site
    resource storage 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2021-06-01' = {
      kind: 'StorageV2'
      location: location
      name: storageName
      properties: {
        supportsHttpsTrafficOnly: true
      }
      sku: {
        name: storageSku
      }
    }
    
    // Compute resources for your Web App
    resource serverfarm 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2021-02-01' = {
      kind: 'app'
      location: location
      name: serverfarmsName
      sku: {
        name: webAppSKU
      }
    }
    
    // Web App that hosts your bot
    resource webApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2021-02-01' = {
      kind: 'app'
      location: location
      name: webAppName
      properties: {
        serverFarmId: serverfarm.id
        httpsOnly: true
        siteConfig: {
          alwaysOn: false
          appSettings: [
            {
              name: 'WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE'
              value: '1' // Run Azure APP Service from a package file
            }
            {
              name: 'WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION'
              value: '~18' // Set NodeJS version to 18.x for your site
            }
            {
              name: 'RUNNING_ON_AZURE'
              value: '1'
            }
            {
              name: 'BOT_ID'
              value: botAadAppClientId
            }
            {
              name: 'BOT_PASSWORD'
              value: botAadAppClientSecret
            }
          ]
          ftpsState: 'FtpsOnly'
        }
      }
    }
    
    // Register your web service as a bot with the Bot Framework
    module azureBotRegistration './botRegistration/azurebot.bicep' = {
      name: 'Azure-Bot-registration'
      params: {
        resourceBaseName: resourceBaseName
        botAadAppClientId: botAadAppClientId
        botAppDomain: webApp.properties.defaultHostName
        botDisplayName: botDisplayName
        microsoftAppTenantId: microsoftAppTenantId
        botAadAppClientSecret: botAadAppClientSecret
        tabDomain: tabDomain
      }
    }
    
    var siteDomain = replace(replace(storage.properties.primaryEndpoints.web, 'https://', ''), '/', '')
    
    // The output will be persisted in .env.{envName}. Visit https://aka.ms/teamsfx-actions/arm-deploy for more details.
    output TAB_AZURE_STORAGE_RESOURCE_ID string = storage.id // used in deploy stage
    output TAB_DOMAIN string = siteDomain
    output TAB_ENDPOINT string = 'https://${siteDomain}'
    output BOT_AZURE_APP_SERVICE_RESOURCE_ID string = webApp.id
    output BOT_DOMAIN string = webApp.properties.defaultHostName
```

azurebot.bicep:

```
    @maxLength(20)
    @minLength(4)
    @description('Used to generate names for all resources in this file')
    param resourceBaseName string
    
    @maxLength(42)
    param botDisplayName string
    
    param botServiceName string = resourceBaseName
    param botServiceSku string = 'F0'
    param botAadAppClientId string
    param botAppDomain string
    param microsoftAppTenantId string
    param tabDomain string
    
    @secure()
    @description('Required by Bot Framework package in your bot project')
    param botAadAppClientSecret string
    
    // Register your web service as a bot with the Bot Framework
    resource botService 'Microsoft.BotService/botServices@2021-03-01' = {
      kind: 'azurebot'
      location: 'global'
      name: botServiceName
      properties: {
        displayName: botDisplayName
        endpoint: 'https://${botAppDomain}/api/messages'
        msaAppId: botAadAppClientId
      }
      sku: {
        name: botServiceSku
      }
    }
    
    // Connect the bot service to Microsoft Teams
    resource botServiceMsTeamsChannel 'Microsoft.BotService/botServices/channels@2021-03-01' = {
      parent: botService
      location: 'global'
      name: 'MsTeamsChannel'
      properties: {
        channelName: 'MsTeamsChannel'
      }
    }
    
    resource botServiceConnection 'Microsoft.BotService/botServices/connections@2021-03-01' = {
      parent: botService
      name: 'conntectorGraph'
      location: 'global'
      properties: {
        serviceProviderDisplayName: 'Azure Active Directory v2'
        serviceProviderId: '30dd229c-58e3-4a48-bdfd-91ec48eb906c'
        scopes: 'User.Read'
        parameters: [
          {
            key: 'clientId'
            value: botAadAppClientId
          }
          {
            key: 'clientSecret'
            value: botAadAppClientSecret
          }
          {
            key: 'tenantID'
            value: microsoftAppTenantId
          }
          {
            key: 'tokenExchangeUrl'
            value: 'api://${tabDomain}/botid-${botAadAppClientId}'
          }
        ]
      }
    }
    
    output CONNECTION_NAME string = botServiceConnection.name
```

azure.parameters.json:

```json
    {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "parameters": {
            "resourceBaseName": {
                "value": "tab${{RESOURCE_SUFFIX}}"
            },
            "storageSku": {
                "value": "Standard_LRS"
            },
            "botAadAppClientId": {
                "value": "${{BOT_ID}}"
            },
            "botAadAppClientSecret": {
                "value": "${{SECRET_BOT_PASSWORD}}"
            },
            "webAppSKU": {
                "value": "F1"
            },
            "botDisplayName": {
                "value": "BOT"
            },
            "microsoftAppTenantId": {
                "value": "${{AAD_APP_TENANT_ID}}"
            },
            "tabDomain": {
                "value": "${{TAB_DOMAIN}}"
            },
            "botAppDomain": {
                "value": "${{BOT_DOMAIN}}"
            }
        }
    }
```

teamsapp.local.yml:

```yaml
    version: v1.2
    
    additionalMetadata:
      sampleTag: TeamsFx:msg-ext-with-tab
    
    environmentFolderPath: ./env
    
    provision:
      - uses: teamsApp/create
        with:
          name: MS_TEAMS_TAB_MSGEXT_local
        writeToEnvironmentFile:
          teamsAppId: TEAMS_APP_ID
      - uses: aadApp/create
        with:
          name: MS_TEAMS_TAB_MSGEXT_local
          generateClientSecret: true
          signInAudience: 'AzureADMyOrg'
        writeToEnvironmentFile:
          clientId: AAD_APP_CLIENT_ID
          clientSecret: SECRET_AAD_APP_CLIENT_SECRET
          objectId: AAD_APP_OBJECT_ID
          tenantId: AAD_APP_TENANT_ID
          authority: AAD_APP_OAUTH_AUTHORITY
          authorityHost: AAD_APP_OAUTH_AUTHORITY_HOST
      - uses: aadApp/update
        with:
          manifestPath: './aad.manifest.json'
          outputFilePath: ./build/aad.manifest.${{TEAMSFX_ENV}}.json
      - uses: botAadApp/create
        with:
          name: BOT-${{TEAMSFX_ENV}}
        writeToEnvironmentFile:
          botId: BOT_ID
          botPassword: SECRET_BOT_PASSWORD
      - uses: arm/deploy
        with:
          subscriptionId: ${{AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID}}
          resourceGroupName: ${{AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME}}
          templates:
            - path: ./infra/azure.bicep
              parameters: ./infra/azure.parameters.json
              deploymentName: Create-resources-for-tab
          bicepCliVersion: v0.9.1
      - uses: script
        with:
          run: echo "::set-teamsfx-env TAB_DOMAIN=localhost:53000";
            echo "::set-teamsfx-env TAB_ENDPOINT=https://localhost:53000";
      - uses: teamsApp/validateManifest
        with:
          manifestPath: ./appPackage/manifest.json
      - uses: teamsApp/zipAppPackage
        with:
          manifestPath: ./appPackage/manifest.json
          outputZipPath: ./appPackage/build/appPackage.${{TEAMSFX_ENV}}.zip
          outputJsonPath: ./appPackage/build/manifest.${{TEAMSFX_ENV}}.json
      - uses: teamsApp/validateAppPackage
        with:
          appPackagePath: ./appPackage/build/appPackage.${{TEAMSFX_ENV}}.zip
      - uses: teamsApp/update
        with:
          appPackagePath: ./appPackage/build/appPackage.${{TEAMSFX_ENV}}.zip
    deploy:
      - uses: devTool/install
        with:
          devCert:
            trust: true
        writeToEnvironmentFile:
          sslCertFile: SSL_CRT_FILE
          sslKeyFile: SSL_KEY_FILE
      - uses: file/createOrUpdateEnvironmentFile
        with:
          target: ./tab/.localConfigs
          envs:
            BROWSER: none
            HTTPS: true
            PORT: 53000
            SSL_CRT_FILE: ${{SSL_CRT_FILE}}
            SSL_KEY_FILE: ${{SSL_KEY_FILE}}
            REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID: ${{AAD_APP_CLIENT_ID}}
            REACT_APP_TENANT_ID: ${{AAD_APP_TENANT_ID}}
            REACT_APP_TAB_ENDPOINT: ${{TAB_ENDPOINT}}
            REACT_APP_START_LOGIN_PAGE_URL: ${{TAB_ENDPOINT}}/auth-start.html
      - uses: file/createOrUpdateEnvironmentFile
        with:
          target: ./bot/.localConfigs
          envs:
            BOT_ID: ${{BOT_ID}}
            BOT_PASSWORD: ${{SECRET_BOT_PASSWORD}}
    projectId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

How to fix it? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is an error in arm deploy which create the following. It will be fixed in the next prerelease version.
Refer to this if you are still facing issues-

https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx/issues/10980

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an inner bug for Teams Toolkit and has been fixed in the pre-release version.

You can try to [Switch to the pre-release version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrR3e.png) in VSCode extension.
Or as this bug is triggered by azure deployment error(expected to show the deployment error to user, but blocked by the inner error), you can try to find the error deployment error in the resource group. [Refer to this](https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx/issues/10980#issuecomment-1982203122). If the deployment error is solved, the error will not be triggered.